# Create HTML table power automate hyperlink

Tags: power-automate

I have requirement in Power Automate where I wanted to display the link for the item of a SharePoint hyperlink column's items.

Scenario:

I have a SharePoint List that has a hyperlink column and I wanted to reflect that URL of the SharePoint columns's items in an email body.

Once the Power automate flow runs successfully I want the link to be clickable:

But in my case, I get the output as text as show below

[image]

In Select Action, I have used this expression to map the value

```
concat('<a href="', item()?['Porject URL'], '">Link for more</a>')
```

And in Send an email(V2) action I have used this expression instead of output of Create HTML Table action.

```
replace(replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_table'), '&lt;','<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&quot;', '"')
```

Can someone please help me out to resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Once the Power automate flow runs successfully I want the link to be clickable:

But in my case, I get the output as text as show below

[image]

Comment: please inspect and share a faulty 'a' tag from the email resulting from your flow (right click then 'View source' in Outlook or Power Automate action outputs).

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some other characters as well which require replacing. I would suggest to double check the Create HTML outputs.

[image]

Normally I also replace **&** and **'** for the Create HTML table action.

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(body('Create_HTML_Table'), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&amp', '&'), '&#39;', '"'), '&quot;', '"')
```